# Is there a free analogue clock that displays in the dock?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, dock

I would like to have an analogue clock displaying right in my OS X dock.

The default clock in the menu bar is too small for me, and it is obviously impossible to drag it into the dock.

If possible, I prefer a free (as in beer) solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrew Choi's [SimpleDockClock](http://members.shaw.ca/akochoi/articles/simple-dock-clock/) does this, although it is not straightforward to change the style.

It looks like this:

[image: SimpleDockClock]

The [source code](http://members.shaw.ca/akochoi/articles/simple-dock-clock/SimpleDockClock-src.zip) and a [binary](http://members.shaw.ca/akochoi/articles/simple-dock-clock/SimpleDockClock.zip) are available.

Comment: It is not available anymore :(